# EF Core: Map property to expression executed in database

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

Suppose we have this data model:

```
public class Model1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Model2> model2s { get; set; }
    // dozens of normal properties following...
}

public class Model2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int model1Id { get; set; }
    public Model1 model1 { get; set; }
    // dozens of normal properties following...
}
```

The goal is to know for every instance of Model1 if it has one or more related Model2.

Possible solutions with drawbacks:

- `dbContext.Model1.Include(x => x.model2s).ToList()` and then check on
  the client side for each element if `x.models2.Any()` (very bad
  performance)
- AutoMapper with a DTO or a manual `.Select(x => new { ... })` creating a new anonymous type (more data models, a lot of boilerplate code)

What I would like is to add a property in Model1 `public bool hasOneOrMoreModel2 { get; set; }` an then in `OnModelCreating` of the DbContext add something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Model1>(entity => 
{
    entity.Property(x => x.hasOneOrMoreModel2).MapTo(x => x.models2.Any());
});
```

or a similar simple solution.
Is that possible? And if not whats preventing implementing that to keep code clean and concise?

Comment: You could do `dbContext.Model1.Include(x => x.model2s.Take(1))`.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for the suggestion! That is very concise and would solve the worst cases where a model1 has 10000's of model2s. The downside is its a bit hacky with potential to shoot yourself in the foot later on.

Comment: You can `ProjectTo` another class derived from your entity that has the extra property. There are also ways to have a computed property on your original model, but I'm not familiar with those.